# How to get connected Wi-Fi Network SSID

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get the name of the WiFi Network I'm currently connected to in Chrome browser?
(Display it in a HTML `<div>` or `<p>`)
I searched Google and only found topics about iOS's [WifiWizard](https://github.com/hoerresb/WifiWizard) but I'm using a Chromebook.

I've seen this on some Google pages like Connectivity diagnostics and OS Settings and Network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an experimental [Network Information API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API) but you can't get a SSID for now.